# php - echo contents of a gz file on the fly without loading in memory

Tags: php, gzip

I have to echo uncompressed contents of a gz file on the fly without loading in memory , possibly using streams/pipe. Any recommendation how to do it.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzopen.php#105676

Comment: Do you mean the compressed, or uncompressed content?

Comment: @fubar- uncompressed contents

Comment: Even simpler is [readgzfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readgzfile.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [zlib stream wrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php):

```php
readfile("compress.zlib:///usr/share/man/pt/man1/debconf.1.gz");
```